# Save image locally using react-native-image-picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-image-picker

I am new to React Native. I am trying to get images from `react-native-image-picker` library and I am trying to get the file path and store it in the redux store to access it later. Rather I am getting a cached file path so I am unable to get the image later if the cache is flushed. Is there any way to get the original file path rather than the cached image path or is there any way to fetch the image and store it locally?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used `AsyncStorage` to store the address of the picked image. and to display it later.

```
import ReactNativeBlobUtil from 'react-native-blob-util'
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
```

```
    const [displayImg, setDisplayImg] = useState<any>(null);
    const colors = useAppTheme();
    const handlerPicker = useCallback(() => {

        launchImageLibrary({ mediaType: 'photo' }).then(r => {

            if (r.assets) {
                const targetDir = ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.dirs.DocumentDir;
                const selectedFile = r.assets[0];
                const fAddr = selectedFile.uri || selectedFile.originalPath;
                if (!fAddr) return;
                const savedAddr = targetDir + `/${selectedFile.fileName}`;
                ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.cp(fAddr, savedAddr).then(_r => {
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('img', savedAddr);
                    setDisplayImg(savedAddr);
                }).catch(_err => {
                    console.error(_err);
                })
            }
        }).catch(err => { console.error(err) })
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('img').then(r => {
            if (r) {
                setDisplayImg(r)
            }
        })
    }, []);
```

```
{displayImg && (
   <Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={{ uri: `${Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '' : 'file://'}${displayImg}` }} />
  )}
```

I don't have the ability to test it on IOS, so I am not sure about the source uri, but it works on my AVD.